Reverse path tracing implementation trouble
I'm trying to implement reverse path tracing (paths starting from the light source) using the math outlined in Veach's thesis where t = 1, aka paths with only one vertex for the eye. For simplicity, I'm using a pinhole camera, the most basic diffuse material, and the most basic diffuse reflection strategy.
My understanding is that, for each vertex v_i on the light path, we connect an edge from v_i to the eye vertex, and shade a pixel (or pixels depending on the filter) based on where that edge intersects the eye's film. The color we shade the pixel depends on the emittance of the light source, the current and past BSDFs, importance at the vertex, and current and past PDFs.
However, I have yet to obtain a physically correct result with my implementation. The math seems relatively simple so I don't know where I'm going wrong, and all of the methods work with normal path tracing. Any suggestions are welcome, thank you.
void LightSample(Scene& scene, Camera& camera, Surface*& screen) {
    std::vector<PathVertex> pathVertices;
    // get camera point
    float3 pCamera = camera.camPos;
    float3 nCamera = camera.ahead;
    float pdfCamera = 1.0f;
    // get light point
    float3 pLight = scene.RandomPointOnLight(RandomFloat(), RandomFloat());
    float3 nLight = scene.GetLightNormal(pLight);
    float pdfLightArea = 1.0f / scene.GetLightArea();

    // set first path vertex (light)
    pathVertices.push_back(PathVertex(float3(1.0f / pdfLightArea), pLight, nLight));
    uint seed = RandomUInt();
    float3 initDir = diffusereflection(nLight, seed);
    float pdfLightDirection = 1 / (2.0f * PI);
    float3 T = pathVertices[0].throughput * abs(dot(initDir, nLight)) / pdfLightDirection;

    Ray ray = Ray(pLight, initDir);
    int lightVertex = 1;

    while (lightVertex < 20) {
        scene.FindNearest(ray);
        if (ray.objIdx == -1) return;
        float3 I = ray.O + ray.t * ray.D;
        float3 N = scene.GetNormal(ray.objIdx, I, ray.D);
        float3 albedo = scene.GetAlbedo(ray.objIdx, I);
        float3 BRDF = albedo * INVPI;
        pathVertices.push_back(PathVertex(T, I, N, BRDF));
        lightVertex++;

        /*
        // RR
        float p = clamp(max(max(T.x, T.y), T.z), 0.0f, 1.0f);
        if (p < RandomFloat()) break;
        else T *= (1.0f / p);
        */

        // generate new diffuse ray
        seed = RandomUInt();
        float3 R = diffusereflection(N, seed);
        float diffusePDF = 1 / (2.0f * PI);
        T *= dot(N, R) * BRDF / diffusePDF;
        ray = Ray(I + (R * EPSILON), R);
    }

    for (int s = 1; s <= lightVertex; ++s) {
        const PathVertex& pv = pathVertices[s - 1];
        float x, y;
        if (!camera.GetPixel(pv.point, x, y)) continue;
        // occlude test
        float3 L = pCamera - pv.point;
        float dist = length(L);
        L /= dist;
        float cos_o = dot(-L, camera.ahead);
        float NdotL = dot(pv.normal, L);
        if (cos_o < 0 || NdotL < 0) continue;
        Ray shadowRay = Ray(pv.point + EPSILON * L, L, dist - 2 * EPSILON);
        if (scene.IsOccluded(shadowRay)) continue;

        float3 fsL;
        float G = NdotL * cos_o / (dist * dist);
        if (s > 1) fsL = pv.BRDF * scene.GetLightColor();
        else fsL = scene.GetLightColor();

        float fsE = camera.We(pv.point);

        float3 pathContribution = fsL * fsE * G * pv.throughput;
        printf("%f %f %f\n", pathContribution.x, pathContribution.y, pathContribution.z);
        camera.film.addSampleFiltered(x, y, pathContribution, screen);
    }
}
```


Welcome to the CG stackexchange! I'd recommend that you post the rendering result so we can infer from the output. Also, it would be good to put a full reference to your code since it might be possible that the functions you call in the snippet are buggy.
